# Get column headers of tree panel in extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

Can anyone let me know how to get the columns header name of tree panel (which were set dynamically) on click of any row in that particular column.

I tried:

```
handler: function(treepanel, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    treepanel.getColumnModel().getColumnAt(colIndex));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
treepanel.getView().getGridColumns()[colIndex]['name'];
```